# update query performance between postSQL and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, comparison, cockroachdb

I am using Mongodb and I have a document which keep increasing and based on the Mongodb schema design guidelines it's something to worry about. I see myself exhausting 255mbs in future in single column.
I am trying to understand if Postgres JSONB will help me but from [stackoverflow thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9809/best-gis-system-for-high-performance-web-application-postgis-vs-mongodb) I understand, that I have high read and write requirement so postgres might be a challenge. I am reading and writing geodata at higher rate.

My requirement is to choose a database which is highly scalable , distributed and support for geo-distributed query.

If someone can add thoughts on cockroachDB would be great,

Answer (score 2):

Comparing CockroachDB to MongoDB isn't really an apples to apples comparison.

To start, CockroachDB can scale out horizontally and maintain serializability no matter how many nodes are in the cluster.

This may affect query performance and is why you might see MongoDB return a successful insert before the system has a chance to catch up.

With that said, a 255mb column is not a problem in CockroachDB. I think where you might see problems in CockroachDB is if your JSONB row is bigger than 1MB in size.

If that's not an issue then CockroachDB is absolutely an option for a highly scalable , distributed and support for geo-distributed query.